# Problema ao referenciar componente no GSAP com Vuejs!

Tags: vue.js, greensock-gsap

Estou implementando uma animação com GSAP no meu projeto, quando uso o `ref` em uma tag comum do html funciona de boa Ex:

```
<div ref="element"></div>
```

Porem quando faço isso em um componente do Vuejs não funciona da forma esperada Ex:

```
<MyComponent ref="element" />
```

Quando dou um console.log nessa ref no método utilizado o retorno é diferente para esses dois casos!

```
move(e) {
  const { element} = this.$refs;

  console.log(defaultAnimation);

  TweenLite.to(element, 0.2, {
    x: -((e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) / 50),
    y: -((e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) / 50)
  });
}
```

No primeiro caso o console.log retorna `<div ref="element"></div>` já no segundo é retornado um Objeto `VueComponent`!

Gostaria de saber se quando é um componente tenho que referenciar de forma diferente para que o GSAP consiga encontrar essa referencia? Obrigado!

Comment: A [documentação](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) especifica _"If used on a plain DOM element, the reference will be that element; if used on a child component, the reference will be component instance"_. Ou seja, "Se usado em um elemento DOM, a referência será aquele elemento; se for usado em um componente, a referência será a instância do componente".
No fim das contas seu código se comporta como o esperado :D

Comment: Humm, entendi mais ou menos.. oque acontece que no caso do componente e efeito não acontece da forma esperada..

Comment: Basta que você teste, se for elemento está OK, se for componente pegue o elemento do componente...